# I've recently been working on a new practice website and I'm having trouble with my hyperlinks

Tags: html, css

Download omisphere

This is a hyperlink that I made because non of my other ones were working and this still didn't work.

Could it be my css?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question doesn't include any code for us to be able to help. Please edit your question to include the relevant information.

Comment: Please, provide your code snippet.

Comment: Always post your code when you ask question on SO

Answer (score 0):

***<a href=*** is what tells the website "what follows is a link".

everything between the quotes ***"http://example.com/download/omisphere.txt"*** is the URL to the file and the name of the file.

***" download>*** is telling the webpage that when the link is clicked, download the file.

***Download Omisphere*** is the part they click on.

Put it all together and you get:

```
<a href="http://example.com/download/omisphere.txt" download>Download Omisphere</a>
```

If this were a real link it would down the file **omisphere.txt** from **http://example.com/download/**

Without seeing what html and css you have so far, it's hard to know what you're talking about.